# .gitignore misses trailing new line in NetBeans 11.x

Tags: git, netbeans

I guess this is asked and answered many times - but I wasn't able to find any of it - so if you know some solution feel free to point it out.

Topic: I recently started using NetBeans (11.2) and its Git plugin to sync some Java projects with GitHub. As I also use some private data (access tokesn, private keys) I selected to ignore them via the context menu. However, after pushing my commit I often see that .gitignore is missing the new line at its end. For me I don't care, although I'd like some "clean" github repo log. So, as I don't want to add the missing new line every time I ignored some file (sometimes netbeans decides on its own to add some files or folders to the ignore list) is there a way to tell NetBeans to please add a new line at the end of .gitignore?

//edit:
I also tried to contact NetBeans team directly - but try to send to git@versioncontrol.netbeans.org only returns this error (tried from multiple differnt mail services):
550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
So I guess this mail address is either wrong or at least wrongly configured.

//edit2:
As mentioned by answer this issue seem to exists since end of April 2011 and may have a chance to get pulled for next release.
Personal side note: I'm surprised this wasn't addressed until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a trivial [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4108). Added [PR](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/2061) for that, you can see the changes. I think it would be fixed in 12.1.

Another solution could be adding a [pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/4024222) but not sure it would work with jgit.

UPDATED: It was fixed in 12.0

Comment: Many thanks for this info. I'm surprised this issue exists since about end of april 2011 and still wasn't addressed yet. *sigh* I only chose NetBeans cause I couldn't got Eclipse to work at all. Sorry I can't upvote as I don't have the needed rep for it, but will do so when I get the 15 rep required. About pre-hook: I'm dev on Windows, so as someone noted about 3 years ago: this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @cryptearth, it could be that the issue in NetBeans was introduced later. You can always accept answer (without up-voting) it doesn't require 15 rep.

Comment: I didn't selected this as answer cause ... well, it doesn't answer my question about how to solve it. It only adds some info about a flaw existing for almost the entire past decade and no-one seemed to care about yet. Same goes for how to add a resource folder in a maven project: the reply I got from one of the devs was that netbeans just acts as a gui wrapper and one has to follow maven. As for my hint to make adding a resource folder via context menu I just got: "we know about it but we will not recreate an existing feature" - as said: I only use netbeans as I couldn't got eclipse to work.

Comment: @cryptearth, just let you know it was fixed in 12.0

Answer (score 0):

Check first if it is a Netbeans format behaviour, that would remove trailing whitespaces (including the eol)

For example: "[Can NetBeans remove trailing whitespace and change tabs to spaces on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360139/6309)" mentions an interesting option:

> Tools > Options > Editor > On Save > Remove Trailing Whitespace From: None / All Lines / Modified Lines Only

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I checked this option mentioned in the provided link, but it's already "none", so I guess this only affects files I edit myself, not when NetBeans (or some plugin) does it by itself. I don't know, but my guess it's the Git plugin itself not correctly adding a trailing new line when a file is ignored via the context menu (or some other event for that matter).